# Combination of while, array, and regex

Tags: regex, perl

The loop fails. What is wrong with the array?

I would like the regex to return `B` when it parses the first string, and `M` when it parses the second string.

How is such an regex constructed?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $a = "0.0 B/s";
my $b = "12.0 MiB/s";

while (defined (my $s = shift ("$a", "$b"))) {

    my $unit = $1 if ($a =~ m/.*([KMGT])i?B\/s$/);
    print "$unit\n";
}
```

Comment: Not addressing the regexp, you should use a simple `foreach` instead of `while(defined(my $s = shift...`, and you're checking `$a` each time through the loop, never `$s`.

Comment: `shift("$a", "$b")`?? First off, why quote the variables? Second off, what makes you think shift works on a list? Third, shift does not take a list of arguments, it takes a single array. Fourth, this is what `for` does: `for my $s ($a, $b)`.

Comment: And then there's still the issue that this regex will not match "0.0 B/s", because it requires exactly 1 K, M, G or T before the optional i and the required B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another substitution:

```
for ($a, $b) {
  if (m!((?:[KMGT]i)?B)/s$!) {
    my $unit = $1; 
    $unit =~ s/(.).*/$1/;
    print "$unit\n" if $unit;
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`shift` is meant to be used with arrays, not lists. If you want to use a `while` loop, you need to pre-declare an array containing `$a` and `$b` (which, by the way, are a bad choice for variable names).

Having said that, a `for` loop construct is the more natural choice here:

```
for my $s ( $var1, $var2 ) { ... }
```

And given that you're trying to extract the measurement unit, why not do things a slightly different way:

```
say for map { my ( $s ) = /$regex/; $s } $var1, $var2;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `while` has issues.
2. You are using variable `$a` inside loop, when  you want to use `$s`.

---

I'd use it this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my $a = "0.0 B/s";
my $b = "12.0 MiB/s";
foreach my $s($a, $b) {
    print $1 if ($s =~ m/.*([KMGT])i?B\/s$/);
}
```

Comment: I can only get it to print `M`, where I would have expected it would output `BM` from the two iterations.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting Your regular expression has an issue here. You are capturing only `([KMGT])`, so you can't expect `BM`.